# ROS.org Instructions

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Quoting from [this page](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/1.3/install),

```
 ROS Users: Only install Gazebo from here, and only follow tutorials from this website. Never use the instructions on ros.org.
```

Wouldn't it make sense to update the instructions on ros.org as well as on this site?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/878/ros.org-instructions/) by [David Lu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/153/david-lu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 111 on 2013-01-16

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/143/bit-pirate/) on 2013-01-16**:
Just saw that the statement for installing version 1.2, which currently comes with ROS, has been changed as well. This doesn't make sense to me, too. Why should one install Gazebo again, if installation works fine "the ROS way" (apt-get install ros-*-gazebo-simulator)?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo is a standalone application that lives outside of ROS. Up to and including G-turtle, ROS has pulled in a specific version of Gazebo in order to maintain ABI and API compatibility with the rest of the ROS ecosystem.

Gazebo will be maintaining ABI and API compatibility, so ROS will transition to using the system install of Gazebo in H-Turtle.

We are telling people to use the standalone version of Gazebo because it is most actively maintained, updated, and tested version.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Not a solution yet but a [ticket](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/roswiki/issues/21) is opened on `ROS wiki`'s issue tracker.

---

Originally posted by [IsaacS](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/15/isaacs/) with karma: 118 on 2013-01-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1